# Escape Character for % in Bash prompt

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have a bat file  Sig.Bat containing :

```
rdiff.exe -b 10240 signature 'D:/test/NZ 100% Pure/ABC.txt' 'D:/test/NZ 100% Pure/ABC.txt.DSS'
```

I excute Sig.Bat with command

```
bash -l -c '"D:/test/Sig.bat"'
```

I Get following Error and no file is created.

> librsync: ERROR: (rs_file_open) Error opening "D:/test/NZ 100/test/NZ 100 Pure/ABC.txt.DSS" for read: No such file or directory

Whereas if I remove the % sign from folder and bat file then the Signature file gets created.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin doesn't understand windows file paths. You can use the `cygpath` utility to get the corresponding cygwin names:

```
cygpath 'D:/test/NZ 100% Pure/ABC.txt'
```